# How to open Javamail attachment with JS

Tags: jakarta-mail, attachment

Im writing a simple email client for Gmail mail server and I'd like to be able to download attachments via web interface made with JS.
I donwloaded attachments into local folder

```
private List<File> getAttachmentsFromMessage (Message message, int j) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    List<File> attachments = new ArrayList<>();

    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount() ; i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase( bodyPart.getDisposition())){

            File file = new File("target\\att\\" + j +"_"+ bodyPart.getFileName());

            ((MimeBodyPart) bodyPart).saveFile(file);
            attachments.add(file);
        }
    }
    return attachments;
}
```

and then try to transfer them to web interface via links

```
for (let j = 0; j <links_to_attachments.length ; j++) {
        attachment_holder = document.createElement('div');
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href','http://localhost/javaProjects/CRM/target/att/1_att1.docx');
        a.download = '1.docx';
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('link'));
        attachment_holder.appendChild(a);
    }
```

But this method didnt work.
And also it seems there is no way to get direct link to attachment.

Could you please to help me with this problem? How could I get these attachments dowmloaded via links?

Comment: Need more information.  What exactly didn't work?  Did you download the attachments using JavaMail?  Are you downloading them to a server or to your local machine?  Do you then have a web application or web server running on that machine that's making the attachment files available to your JavaScript application?  Is your JavaScript application running on the same machine where the files are stored?  Is it running in the browser or in a server (e.g., node.js)?

Comment: Thank you for input, Bill. I have already managed issue with using of external Web Server (plug in for Chrome), mapped for folder where I stored attachments to, This allowed me to address folder from JS with 'http://...' ulr and problem was solved